# Change timepicker field based on changes in datepicker field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, timepicker

In one of my project I need to provide following feature. I am useing jQueryUi datepicker and timepicker plugin from this source (http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

1. When a user selects date from datepicker field: if the date is equal to todays date, then the timepicker field will only allow to select time that is equal to current time and above. For example today is 20 Nov. if the selected date is also 20 Nov, then the current time i.e say 3.15pm is the minTime that user can select and time before that will be disabled. minTime feature is provided in the plugin.
2. If the user selects date that is greater than today's date then the minTime will default to 10am.
3. This should change with the change in the datefield. SO I think `.change()` must be used. I tried using it. It does change on the first selection but if I change the same datefield again, the timepicker field does not change. Here is my code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vivpad/262x159b/

   ```
   <div class="row">
   <div class="small-6 columns">
   <label>TimePicker
       <input type="text" class="timepicker">
   </label>
   </div>
   <div class="small-6 columns">
   <label>DatePicker
       <input type="text" class="datepicker">
   </label>
   </div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.7/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
   ```

Jquery, jQueryUI and above timepicker scripts have been used

```
var fullDate = new Date();
console.log(fullDate);
var twoDigitMonth = (fullDate.getMonth() + 1) + "";
if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1) twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
if (twoDigitDate.length == 1) twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" +      fullDate.getFullYear();
console.log(currentDate);

var dt = new Date();
var currentTime = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
console.log(currentTime);

$('.timepicker').timepicker({
'minTime': '10.00am',
    'maxTime': '11:30pm',
    'showDuration': true
});

$("#datepicker, .datepicker").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

});

$('.datepicker').change(function () {

});
```

Comment: Use the [datepicker's `onSelect` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) to set the timepicker's `minTime` to the current time if the date is today. Alternatively use the datepair plugin that the timepicker plugin examples page points to

Comment: @blgt how do I pass this variable dateText from onSelect to .change event